# How do I synchronize 2 processes in threads so they run together?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, synchronization

I currently have this code (thanks for the help from here). I need to create the first ProcessMessage as a thread and run the second `ProcessMessage` synchronously (on the current thread), then perform the Join on the single thread.  Otherwise, I'll have three threads doing effectively two things. How do I modify this to accomplish it? I am on .NET 3.5

```
Thread thRegion1 = new Thread(() =>
{
    if (Region1.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        returnMessage = ProcessTheMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region1));
        Logger.Log(returnMessage);
    }
});

Thread thRegion2 = new Thread(() =>
 {
     if (Region2.Trim().Length > 0)
     {
         returnMessage = ProcessTheMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region2));
         Logger.Log(returnMessage);
     }
 });

thRegion1.Start();
thRegion2.Start();

thRegion1.Join();
thRegion2.Join();
```

Comment: The thread that runs this code isn't getting any work done.  So start only one thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Thread thRegion1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            if (shawRegion1.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, 
                                                             shawRegion1));
                Logger.Log(returnMessage);
            }
        });

thRegion1.Start();

if (shawRegion2.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, shawRegion2));
    Logger.Log(returnMessage);
}

thRegion1.Join();
```

This starts the `thRegion1` thread and performs the other part of the work in the current thread. After that work is finished, it calls `Join` on `thRegion1` which will return immediately, if `thRegion1` is already finished with its work.

Comment: Thanks. But where is thRegion2? Should I remove it from this line from the second process? Thread thRegion2 = new Thread(() => ?

Comment: @Ree Yes, it was removed, and the work it was doing was moved to the *current thread.* Why have it stay idle when it could be doing useful work?

Comment: `thRegion2` isn't needed and because of this, it doesn't exist in my code anymore. The work it does has been moved to the current thread as you requested.

Comment: So will this make the 2 reagions process in concurrent channels?

Comment: @Ree Yes, the first one started in a new thread, and the second one is running at your current thread, so they are both running concurrently.